# Parse HTML Formatted Email (not URL) into VBA

Tags: html, vba, email, parsing

**Context**

I am receiving emails formatted to HTML.
The email has a table in it.
I would like to parse the table so that I can access the individual cells in the table.

As per the numerous questions and answers on SO, I have found out that the way to access this is to do something like this:

```
objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("td")
```

...which will create an array (group) of the columns in the HTML file. So that's sorted.

**Question:**

Instead of objIE.document. which  in the numerous SO  examples points to some URL, I want to point it to the email in this specific case. In this specific case my email is called "Msg" which I have made by doing:

```
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
```

In my code, I have therefore done the following:

```
 Msg.Body.getElementsByTagName ("td")
```

However I get an error saying "invalid qualifier" error on that line when trying to run it.

Any ideas on how to access the tables cells/elements?

Comment: Have you tried using the [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941.aspx) property of the [MailItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332.aspx)?

Comment: I seem to be one step closer. Testing = item.HTMLBody works and when I console log out it shows one big HTML message, thanks. Now when I do Testing.getElementsByTagName("p")(0) I should get the first paragraph of the email  but get an error "invalid qualifier"

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that should get you pretty close. What you want to do is store the HTML of the email into a HTML file, that way you can use element selectors to find what you are interested in. This code **requires** a reference to the Outlook Object.

Here is a brief example.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SOTest()
    Dim outlook     As outlook.Application
    Dim ns          As outlook.NameSpace: Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim folder      As outlook.MAPIFolder: Set folder = ns.PickFolder
    Dim item        As outlook.MailItem
    Dim html        As Object: Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Dim elements    As Object
    Dim element     As Object

    For Each item In folder.Items
        If item.Class = olMail Then ' Make sure it's a Mail Item...change if not needed
            html.Body.Innerhtml = item.HTMLBody ' set the body of the email equal to the html from outlook email
            Set elements = html.getElementsByTagName("td")
            For Each element In elements
                Debug.Print element.InnerText
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```